# How to add value of the every key in python Dictionary from different files

Tags: python, dictionary

Good day everyone. Still fighting with python dict. and, as i think, my last problem with it. At first, i am creating structure of my dictionary with first data:

```
for i, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(faces):
        face = dict()
        face["face_{}".format(i)] =  {"face_rect": str((x, y, w, h)), "Age": "howold", "Gender": "who"}
        with open('face.json', 'a') as fp:
            data_to_write = json.dumps(face)
            fp.write(data_to_write + '\n')
```

After this part of code my face.json looks like:

- {"face_0": {"face_rect": "(325, 65, 74, 74)", "Age": "howold", "Gender": "who"}}
- {"face_1": {"face_rect": "(200, 77, 67, 67)", "Age": "howold",
  "Gender": "who"}}
- {"face_2": {"face_rect": "(467, 72, 66, 66)", "Age": "howold",
  "Gender": "who"}}
- {"face_3": {"face_rect": "(51, 70, 86, 86)", "Age": "howold",
  "Gender": "who"}}
- {"face_4": {"face_rect": "(593, 58, 74, 74)", "Age": "howold",
  "Gender": "who"}}

At the another py file i have another process, what should add Gender "who". And, at 3rd py file should and Age "howold". I tried to write at the 2nd file something like:

```
face = dict()
face["Gender"] = Guess
with open('face.json', 'a') as fp:
     data_to_write = json.dumps(face)
     fp.write(data_to_write + '\n')
```

And a lot of kind of it, but doesn't work for me. It's rewrite all my face.json file or just write new lines with another structure.
Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE------------------------------**
First part of code using with every picture what i have, it's face detection. It's writing coordinates or rectangle in dictionary, what i am creating at the same time. You can see structure. Let me show full def of 2nd file, from where i need to grab next data:

```
def classify(sess, label_list, softmax_output, coder, images, image_file):

print('Running file %s' % image_file)
image_batch = make_batch(image_file, coder, not FLAGS.single_look)
batch_results = sess.run(softmax_output, feed_dict={images:image_batch.eval()})
output = batch_results[0]
batch_sz = batch_results.shape[0]
for i in range(1, batch_sz):
    output = output + batch_results[i]

output /= batch_sz
best = np.argmax(output)
best_choice = (label_list[best], output[best])
Guess = 'Guess @ 1 %s, prob = %.2f' % best_choice
print('Guess @ 1 %s, prob = %.2f' % best_choice)
face = dict()
face["Gender"] = Guess
with open('face.json', 'a') as fp:
     data_to_write = json.dumps(face)
     fp.write(data_to_write + '\n')
```

From here, as you can see, i need to grab Guess data, to the dict, what already created. Relationship between this 2 files - at first face detection, creating dict., and crop face's on image. After it we will not use detector again, but we have rect. coordinates, what i just want to see in json file. After it, code of 2nd file (classify), gives result (prediction) to me about Age or Gender. It's text format. So, what i want to have after all it - json file with all of data: face_rect,Age,Gender. How to update it?

```
if label_list == ['M', 'F']:    
        face = dict()
        face["face_{}".format(n)] = {"Gender": Guess}
        with open('face.json', 'a') as fp:
            data_to_write = json.dumps(face)
            fp.write(data_to_write + '\n')
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you are trying to do here. What is the relationship between these two snippets? How are they called? What is the intended output?

Comment: Hello! I wrote big update at the main post, read it please. If you still have question - feel free to ask!